# Arrays localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, local-storage

I've got the following pair Key / Value in localStorage:

Key: events

Value:

```
   [
      {'Date': '4-5-2015', 
      'Event': 'Theater', 
      'Duration': '2 hours'},

     {'Date': '4-5-2015', 
      'Event': 'Bowling', 
      'Duration': '3 hours in the evening'},

      ...

     {'Date': '10-5-2015', 
      'Event': 'Driving', 
      'Duration': '4 hours of driving'},

    ];
```

That code is for Calendar. Only one event per day is possible. My problem is that I can't remove a previous data of a day when storing a newer one for the same day.

What I need is a universal decision based on Javascript, which can "reach" the stored data by let's say Date qualifier only. Thus, we delete the "old" Event and Duration and then store a "new" one.

```
      for (i=0; i<events.length; i++) {

          if(newDate == yetStoredDate) {
          events[i].Event.removeItem(?) //How to refer only this Event?
          events[i].Duration.removeItem((?) //How to refer only this Duration?
           };

       };
```

I aslo tried splice() method, but it seems to workk only for removing the whole block {Date / Event / Duration}. I didn't manage to get to the specific element with its help.

Answer (score 0):

to refer only to the element of array and change the local storage you need try:

```
        localStorage.setItem("events", JSON.stringify(events));
        for (i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
            if('4-5-2015' == events[i].Date) {
                events[i].Event = "new value";
                events[i].Duration = "new value";
                var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("events"));
                x[i] = events[i];
                localStorage.setItem("events", JSON.stringify(x));
            };
        };
```

hope this could help you

Comment: Yeah, it works, but it doesn't refer to the stored data. It can change the visual one, but I need to remove from localStorage the "old" data, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this using LocalStorage is to just set the entire value for the key. There isn't any reference to the LocalStorage item, you just `get` or `set` it. So you can't change one part of the value without actually updating the whole of it to remove the deleted parts.

I just used a LocalStorage wrapper to handle updating the key, values within the actual value of LocalStorage (using JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`delete events[i]` within your if clause, then add the new event and save the changed JSON to the localStorage.